# Why do model selection criteria (xICs, etc) not explicitly incorporate a loss function?

Tags: model-selection, aic, kullback-leibler, bic

*Model Selection and Multimodel Inference* by Burnham and Anderson notes that TIC, AIC, AICc and QAICc are based on K-L distance between a given model and true model. Also BIC is in a sense based on such a distance (1 if and only if the model is equal to the true model).

Elsewhere in stats, people are explicit about loss functions, because these can genuinely incorporate domain-specific differences/preferences. Why do we not incorporate such a loss function into model selection, realised as a distance between the distributions specified by two models?

[This q. is motivated by trying to understand why K-L distance is a natural choice *for model selection*. I understand it's information theoretic properties, but it's not clear to me why those make it a good choice for model selection.]

Comment: Kullback-Leibler distance *is* a loss function, and it's closely related to the log likelihood, which is also a loss function. The idea is to get as close as possible to the true unknown data generating process. I am a little unclear on what you are asking. Are you thinking in terms of cost sensitive learning, where the goal is not to approximate a conditional distribution, but to make cost-optimal decisions without the intermediate step of fitting a distribution?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Sorry to be unclear. I was wondering why one did not get results stated in terms of a generic loss function $L$. So e.g. what happens if you take the proof of AIC (which I have not yet grokked) and replace $D_{KL}(p, q)$ with a generic $L(p, q)$?

Comment: @StephanKolassa More generally, I'm trying to understand what motivates the use of K-L distance rather than any other distance/loss-function. It feels like there must be some cost/utility assumptions implicit in that choice, and I would like to understand what they are. Working from the general theory (for an arbitrary loss fn $L$) seems like one way to do that.